# Как выгрузить c# библиотеку из CLR, не завершая процесса

Tags: c#, dll, clr

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно выгрузить с# библиотеку из нативного кода или как-то изнутри самой библиотеки.

Дело в том, что есть нативное оконное приложение на delphi. Для него мной был написан плагин на с# с вызовом функции, внутри которой стартует отдельный поток с wpf приложением и запуском окна, но внутри основного процесса.

В приложении на delphi dll подключается с помощью WinAPI (LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress и FreeLibrary). Так вот, при освобождении с помощью FreeLibrary плагин на самом деле не освобождается, а продолжает висеть в CLR вплоть до завершения процесса.

В англоязычном сегменте, нашёл ответ, что нужно выгружать AppDomain, но без примеров. Как в моём случае решить данную проблему, откуда выгружать AppDomain, каким образом?

Экспортируемая функция внутри C# либы выглядит следующим образом:

```cs
 public static int showCyclegramm(IntPtr allWindowsClosedCallback)
        {
            if (_wpfLoaded)
                App.ShowWindow();
            else
            {
                _thread = new Thread(App.StartWpf);
                _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                _thread.Start(allWindowsClosedCallback);
                _wpfLoaded = true;
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

StartWpf это по сути тот же main из обычного WPF приложения:

```cs
public static void StartWpf(object allWindowsClosedCallback)
        {
            var cPointer = (IntPtr) allWindowsClosedCallback;
            if (cPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
                _allClosedWindowsAction =
                    Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<Action>((IntPtr) allWindowsClosedCallback);

            try
            {
                _app = new App();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Последнее окно было закрыто. Перезагрузите библиотеку");
                return;
            }

            _app.InitializeComponent();
            _app.Run();
        }
```

Comment: Почитай про плагинную систему, там хороший пример как загружать выгружать различные dll. Как правило предлагается создавать сабдомены для запуска сторонних dll, а потом просто убиваешь (выгружаешь) этот сабдомен и все.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET Core начиная с версии 3.0 поддерживается [выгрузка DLL без использования доменов приложений](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability-howto). В .NET Framework для того, чтобы DLL можно было выгрузить, ее необходимо загрузить в отдельный домен приложений и осуществлять любое взаимодействие с ней через класс-обертку, производный от MarshalByRefObject. Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void PrintLibs()
        {
            Process pr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();            

            using (pr)
            {
                pr.Refresh();

                foreach (ProcessModule mod in pr.Modules)
                {
                    if(mod.ModuleName.EndsWith(".ni.dll"))Console.WriteLine(mod.ModuleName);
                }         
            }            
        }        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //создаем домен приложений
            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");

            //создаем обертку для удаленных вызовов
            Type type = typeof(Wrapper);
            Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                type.Assembly.FullName,
                type.FullName);

            //вызываем метод в MyDomain
            string s = wrapper.Invoke("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor", "Name");
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.WriteLine("*** Загруженные библиотеки до выгрузки домена: ***");
            PrintLibs();

            //выгружаем MyDomain
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.WriteLine("*** Загруженные библиотеки после выгрузки домена: ***");
            PrintLibs();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public class Wrapper : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string Invoke(string query, string property)
        {
            string assemblyPath = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\System.Management.dll";
            Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
            Type t = ass.GetType("System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher");

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t, query);
            IEnumerable moc = (obj as dynamic).Get();
            foreach (object item in moc)
            {
                return (item as dynamic).Properties[property].Value.ToString();
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
}

/* Результат:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz
*** Загруженные библиотеки до выгрузки домена: ***
mscorlib.ni.dll
System.ni.dll
System.Core.ni.dll
Microsoft.CSharp.ni.dll
System.Management.ni.dll
System.Dynamic.ni.dll
*** Загруженные библиотеки после выгрузки домена: ***
mscorlib.ni.dll
System.ni.dll 
*/
```